# What is the part of speech of 'up' in the following sentences

Tags: prepositions, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

1. He looked up and saw the stars.
2. The time is up.
3. The list is full of some ups and downs.
4. He has just been upped to the position of a president.

My answers are:

1. Adverb 2. Adjective 3. Noun 4. Verb

But I don't know if I am on the right page.

Please if there is a method or trick for Identifying a part of speech in a sentence I would also love to know.

Comment: You can use a dictionary, there are plenty available on line. It will be more beneficial if you research this yourself. Then if you have a specific problem you can ask a question on this site. Please be specific and try to avoid using a list of examples, like above.

Comment: full of ups and downs/upped to the position of president.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in all 4.

> He looked up and saw the stars.
> The time is up.
> The list is full of some ups and downs.
> He has just been upped to the position of a president.

Roles of the various forms of 'up':
(1) it describes the verb 'looked' and hence is adverb.
(2) it follows a verb of being.  This is a subject complement and is either an adverb of time or place, or an adjective.  In this case, it is adjective.
(3) it is the object of preposition 'of' and has to be a noun.
(4) it is the passive form of the action verb 'up' and is hence a verb.